# RichTextField vs NoteField class

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spfield, rich-text

I'm about to create a field called details so I was thinking to make it a NoteField then I discoverd RichTextField.

And I found out that RichTextField inherits from NoteField which is a text box for recording notes with multiple lines, so what's the difference that RichTextField has brought to this control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RichTextField allows you to format the text, while NoteField is just plain text.